# Nlog Issues With Multiple Logging Implementations

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using `NLog` in my `Web API` project and I'm having an issue with the incorrect log be written to after a particular sequence of operations. There is an underlying 3rd party reference that uses it's own NLog logging and configuration. So here is what happens in order:

1. My app logs to *my* log in **Location A** = Success
2. Underlying 3rd party .dll logs to *its* log in **Location B** = Success
3. My app *attempts* to log to **Location A** but the content is still written to **Location B**

I'm using the following configuration:

```
<logger name="MyLogger" minlevel="Info,Warn,Error,Debug,Fatal,Trace" levels="Info,Warn,Error,Debug,Fatal,Trace"  writeTo="FileLog" />
```

Upon creating my logger in the constructor of a wrapper class I have the following (simplified) to make sure I grab the correct `logger`:

```
private readonly Logger logger;
public LogException()
{
    logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");           
}
```

Also, the underlying .dll is not requiring me to add it's NLog configuration to the `nlog.config' file in the host app.It has the following configuration for resolving it's logger dependency:

```
  <ioc type="Common.Container.SimpleDependencyResolver, Common" />
  <container>
    <components>
      <component service="Common.Diagnostics.ILogFactory, Common" type="Diagnostics.NLog.LoggerFactory, Diagnostics.NLog" scope="Transient" />
    </components>
  </container>
```

When I inspect the `logger` factory within, it's pointing to the log file at **Location B** and not my **Location A**.

Bottom line is, once that 2nd logger, writes it overtakes my ability to log to my log even though I'm instantiating the logger by it's given name. Any ideas on what I might be missing so that subsequent calls log to my log?